# Can I use HTML5 download attribute in anchor tag using an API (instead of direct link)?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I have a web page (served from, say, [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) domain after user logged in) that has following html element.

```
<a href="../api/values/import" download>Download Import File</a>
```

The import file is currently saved in a azure storage as a blob. Assume that the blob (i.e. import file) requires temporary SAS token (created for logged in user) to be accessed:

```
https://foo.blob.core.windows.net/myfiles/import.txt?(sasTokenInfo)
```

All of this can be simplified if the anchor tag can be used as shown below:

```
<a href="https://foo.blob.core.windows.net/myfiles/import.txt?(sasTokenInfo)" download>Download Import File</a>
```

However this runs the risk of expired sasTokenInfo before user clicks on it. The user may linger on this page (which has other info on it) sufficiently long enough for the sasToken to expire. The simplest thing to do here is to create sasToken for longer period. But I don't want to do that.

I am trying to find out if better solution is to use the API as shown at the beginning. When the user clicks on the above anchor link (i.e "../api/values/import"), the idea is to have this API create the blob sasToken for this user and send the link (that contains this sasToken) to the above blob storage import file. The idea is not to read this file in the above API but simply send the link to it so that browser can download it directly without involving the domain [www.foo.com](http://www.foo.com). To facilitate this, I thought if I can have the following header information, I would be able to force the browser to download this file directly from azure blob storage on the browser's machine:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="https://foo.blob.core.windows.net/myfiles/import.txt"
```

Apparently, the value of "filename" (from Content-Disposition header value) should not contain path info (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition). This means I am not able to set the direct blob storage related link in this header value.

Questions:

1. Is the API route a viable option?
2. If yes, then how can I send a link to a file in the azure storage through my API to the browser so that browser can automatically download the file?
3. What do I need to do in my asp net core web API for (2)?
4. What do I need to do on the client-side html pages for (2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If yes, then how can I send a link to a file in the azure storage through my API to the browser so that browser can automatically download the file?

I suggest you could use ajax to let the web api to generate the blob url and then create the herf html to download it inside the succss method.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

Client ajax:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://localhost:7204/api/values/Download',
        method: 'GET',
        success: function (data) { 
             var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = data;
            link.download = 'myFile.txt'; // Set the file name here               
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('Failed to download file.');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Web API:

```
[HttpGet("Download")]
public string GetUrl() {


    return "https://localhost:7204/111.txt";
}
```

Result:

It will download the file automatically.

[image]

Comment: Your example shows the hosts are same for API and file (“localhost:7204”). Will it work if they are different?

Comment: I tested it with one host for API and another for file. It works. However instead of showing the download dialog, the above code simply navigates to the download link file. Weird, may be it is my setup.